# Roberto The Insane Robot

Tags: futurama

Roberto was the first insane robot built by a team of scientists.  He always carries a stabbing knife which he uses it to rob banks or mug people.

Since he uses his stabbing knife frequently and considering his mental illness, has he ever killed anyone with his stabbing knife or with any other type of weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roberto, as a king in Cornwood in Bender's Game, sent his army to their deaths by declaring war on the scallops, tying the army to a boulder and pushed them into the sea.  That's the only instance of him killing anyone, and it was in a game/imaginary world.  Every other appearance has merely involved wounding to varying degrees, or was a harmless cameo.

Answer (score 1):

In "Crimes of the Hot" after Bender reveals that Nixon is about to kill them, in the ensuring chaos Roberto is seen stabbing a Robot in the chest.
Through the series he almost kills people dozens of times and talks about how he recently killed people constantly. So it can be assumed, even though we don't exactly see it, he kills people.